# Frame Dragging by Sag A star

Tags: black-holes, orbital-motion, galaxies, milky-way, frame-dragging

Is frame dragging by the supermassive black hole Sag A responsible for the milky way's rotation?  If so would we also be part of time dilation depending on how close we are to Sag A?  Is the gravity created by dark matter responsible for that instead? But since we can prove one and not the other, I'm confused to which would be a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sagittarius A$^*$ may seem big (4 million Solar masses) but compared to the whole galaxy it's peanuts. The Milky Way is around a million times more massive. If we consider size instead of mass the difference is even more stark. Sagittarius A$^*$ has a radius of around $0.000001$ light years while the Milky Way has a radius of about $100000$ light years.

The reason size matters is that frame dragging effects are only large once we get within a few tens of the Schwarzschild radius, which for Sagittarius A$^*$ would be around $0.00001$ light years. Even if we are charitable and say the frame dragging might be detectable at hundreds of Schwarzschild radii the length scale is still tiny compared to the Milky Way as a whole.

So while Sagittarius A$^*$ may well have been instrumental in the formation of the Milky Way it now plays no significant role in its dynamics. If it were to be magically removed from the Milky Way it would make very little difference.

Comment: Thank  you @John Rennie.  This greatly helps me understand the scale at which frame dragging has an effect on the outer arms of our galaxy.